# ifdef & solaris

Tags: c, solaris

I want to undefine variable when compiling on SunOS. Therefore, i tried to put

```
#ifdef SunOS
#undef FOO
#endif
```

but it does not work. The problem is in #ifdef sunos ? Should i declarate it, or complier do it by itself ?

regards
S.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any compilers for Solaris that predefine `SunOS` for you.

The Sun compilers list the macros they predefine in the 'cc' man page under the `-D` option description, including `__sun` and `__SunOS_5_10` (for uname -r of "5.10"), but not just plain `SunOS`.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler will include a number of variables predefined.  See your compiler documentation to find out what that list is.

If you're trying to make a piece of software buildable on multiple (unixlike) platforms, then take a look at [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).  It has a bit of a learning curve, but pays off very handsomely in the long term.

**Addition:**
Also, your compiler might have a way of listing the predefined macros.  For example, using gcc, `touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h` produces a list of all of then, which comes to 119 with gcc on OS X.  But the documentation will probably give some indication of that compiler's *recommended* macros for this (but autoconf remains a better technique for this in general).

Comment: C/C++ is missing a directive:  #ifndef(::int sum(vector<int>)) , or whatever.   As a result, millions of lines of hacky autoconf junk have had to be maintained by hundreds of thousands of developers.   Fixing this will lead to global peace.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with that, `cpp` accept that fragment just fine. What's the problem you're seeing?